# Understanding Linear (In)Dependency on polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

There is an existing theorem that states that *if polynomials have distinct degrees, they are linearly independent.*

For example, if we were to find a basis of P3 containing the *independent set* {1 + x, 1 + x^2}, we can extend the basis by adding any *distinct* vectors from the standard basis of P3 - {1, x, x^2, x^3}.

In this case, we will choose {1, x^3} to extend the basis and making it linearly independent because these have distinct degrees. So the answer is: **{1, 1 + x, 1 + x^2, x^3}**

I understand this so far.
Now, there is a different example associated with extending B1= {x , 1+2x^2 } to a basis of P2.

A basis is linearly independent, implying that we use distinct degrees to extend, so we should choose {1}

But the book shows that {x, 1+2x^2, x^2} is a basis of P2.

We can check for linear independence:
0(x) + 0(1+2x^2) + 0(x^2) = 0 is the only way to get 0. Which means they are independent. This however contradicts the previous theorem, because we have x^2 in two terms. The degrees are no longer distinct.

Is this an exception to the theorem or am I missing something?

Comment: Degrees need not be distinct. For example, $\{1+x, 1-x\}$ are lineraly independent.

Comment: You are using the converse of that therorem.